# Pyodbc -Iterating over results of query and get counts

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to get count from results of tables which is from another query execution but I am getting error:

```
import pandas.io.sql
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
server = '<Sample server>'
database = 'ABC'
username = 'scott'
password = 'tiger'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password,autocommit=False)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

query = "select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where table_catalog='ABC' and table_type='BASE TABLE'"

cursor.execute(query)

for row in cursor:
print(row.TABLE_NAME)
a=str(row.TABLE_NAME)
print(a)
res=cursor.execute('select count(*) from  '+a)
for i in res:
       print(i)
```

Getting error

I am trying to get all `table_names` and their row counts

```
TABLE_NAME , COUNT
-------------------
EMPLOYEE,2213
DEPARTMENTS,12
LOCATION,10
```

Can you please help how can I achieve this?

Comment: It looks like you need to indent the last 3 lines of your code properly so that they are executed inside of the `for` loop.

Comment: What is the error message you receive? Please edit post with it.

Comment: Hi , my indentation in query is properly placed .While pasting in above post it might got wrong


from above code i m able to print count only for one table , there are lot more tables exits for that database

Comment: Please answer what the error message you receive.

Comment: Error is something like below
Employee_list_20190322
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-f528a1134d4a> in <module>
     23     a=(row.TABLE_NAME)
     24     print(a)
---> 25     res=cursor.execute('select count(*) as count  from'+a).fetchall()
     26     for i in res:
     27         print(i.count)

ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'from Employee_list_20190322'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Answer (score 2):

Consider one query joining to *sys* tables:

```
query = """SELECT 
             i.TABLE_NAME,
             p.[Rows] AS [COUNT]
           FROM 
             sys.tables t
           INNER JOIN 
             sys.partitions p ON t.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID
           INNER JOIN
             information_schema.tables i ON t.[NAME] = i.TABLE_NAME 
                                        AND i.table_catalog = 'ABC'
                                        AND i.table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
        """

cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for the query ..This query will work however i m trying to find solution using above approach  ,one to read from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.table and then result of which needs to be looped to get table count for each table .